# Why choose AWS RDS (or any cloud RDS) instead of standalone MySQL?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I want some assistance to help me understand which solution to choose. I have a Web App with around 1000 active monthly clients, and a database of 40GB size (unzipped). At the moment I am hosting MySQL server on a dedicated root server, with 64GB RAM, 4TB HDD, and Intel i7 CPU.

The modern trend nowadays is everyone to switch to Cloud RDS(either AWS, Azure, GCP, DigitalOcean etc). What are the benefits of hosting your DB to cloud providers?

Ok i can understand that in case of disaster you will have the option to revert easily in a working state, however is that all? The pricing is way higher so you can "just have a restore back in 10-20 minutes".

Consider your answer having in mind that I have a simple web app and not complex corporate procedures/scenarios!

Comment: There are a lot more features to RDS than just point-in-time restores. Quick and easy management of read replicas, high availability failover, multi-datacenter redundancy, etc. Whether these are *worth it* to you is an opinion only you can really determine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The benefits are:

1. You don't have to know how to administer the operating system
2. The configured defaults for the database server are *slightly*
   better then the standalone defaults (they adjust
   innodb_buffer_pool_size to match the instance size by default).
3. RDS does routine system administration for you, such as database upgrades (be aware of the risks), database backups (saves you two lines of a shell script in cron), and lets you recovery to point in time (of course, you can do this yourself simply enough, too).
4. RDS has features such as multi AZ (for redundancy) (you can just as easily do this without RDS) and read replicas (for scale) which are (negligibly) easier to set up than using native tools.
5. RDS can be fully set up using CloudFormation infrastructure as code (not exactly RDS specific).

The drawbacks are:

1. It will be more expensive
2. It will be slower
3. It will be more opaque when it comes to troubleshooting
4. Several performance and cost optimisation avenues will be unavailable

With a properly configured self-maintained system, it is at least as quick and easy to revert to a working state / restore from a snapshot.

Comment: Really slower? I thought speed was a reason people use Cloud RDS!

Comment: @Leonidas Not generally, no. People use it to avoid having to have a DBA and sysadmin employed. It simplifies all sorts of operational work, but it's a VM and the EBS disks are accessed over the network.

Comment: @Leonidas not even close. Everything virtualized is slower than bare metal, often by a huge margin. 30% is not unheard of, depending on your workload. https://shatteredsilicon.net/blog/2020/03/19/virtual-performance-or-lack-thereof/

Comment: RDS may be marginally slower than running MySQL on a bare metal but it's not slower than running your own MySQL on EC2. Anyway if you move the DB to the cloud you should move the Application there as well - you want the DB close to the App.

Comment: @MLu it absolutely is slower even in EC2 vs RDS comparison. You cannot run your own custom binary build, you cannot run it on ZFS for substantial disk I/O reduction and space saving through lz4 compression, and other things you can tune due to atomic commits, better malloc implementation, etc, etc, etc. Remember that it is not in AWS interest for your system to run fast, it is in their interest for it to run just fast enough that you don't leave and just slow enough that you have to rent a bigger instance.

Comment: /me facepalms after reading @GordanBobic comment.

Comment: @MLu you can facepalm all you want, I can demonstrably run at ~40% lower cost for same performance in EC2 than RDS. When you have customers that spend 6-figures per month on their AWS bill, that becomes significant.